# Filling station is being supplied with drinking water once a week. If its weekly volume of sales in thousands of gallons is R.V with $pdf$ given by

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

PROBLEM: A filling station is being supplied with drinking water once a week. if its weekly volume of sales in thousands of gallons is random variable with pdf given by:

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
5(1-x)^{4}, \text {} 0<x<1 \\
\ 0, \text{} otherwise 
\end{cases}
$

What must the capacity of the tank be so that the probability of the supply's being exhausted in a given week is $0.01?$

MY WORKING:

As far as I have understood the problem is asking for value of $x$ where $P(X)=0.01$, but I am not sure. Can anyone guide me or give a hint?

Comment: You want x such that $\int_0^x 5(1- t)^4 dt= 0.99$.

Comment: Seems $X \sim \mathsf{Beta}(1, 5).$ Then quantile .$99,$ computed in R is given by R code `qbeta(.99, 1, 5)`, which returns $ 0.6018928.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a value of $x$ that has a chance of $0.01$ of being exceeded.  You are given a pdf.  What you really want is a cdf, which is the integral of the pdf from $-\infty$ to $x$ of the pdf and represents the chance that the random variable is less than $x$.  You want the $x$ that makes the cdf equal to $0.99$